# What does the relative sum of squares error signify in neural network analysis in SPSS?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What range of values of the relative sum of sqaures error is acceptable for a good neural network? I am getting around 0.9 of the relative error for 1 model and around 0.4 for another. Are both the networks significant?

Comment: Is the network being used for classification or regression ?

Comment: It is being used for regression!

Comment: Are you happy with both those levels of error for estimating your target function ?

Comment: Thats the problem! I do not know the significance of the term 'relative sum of squares error'. Are these errors out of 1? Meaning, does 0.9 mean 90% error? Or is it some other way? Please tell me the significance of the term 'relative sum of squares error'.

Comment: Also, is there some way to calculate RMSE in SPSS Neural Network analysis? Like instead of relative sum of squares error i want to calculate the RMSE of the network.

Comment: Have you seen ..http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71315/whats-relative-error-in-a-neural-network-model and this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_idd_mlp_output.htm

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~adelle/Garvan/Assays/GoodnessOfFit.html):

> A value closer to 0 indicates that the model has a smaller random error component, and that the fit will be more useful for prediction.